# What's the point of using anchor in <a id='top'>Top of page</a>?

Tags: html, browser

The first Google [search result](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) for "html links" says (paraphrased) that to create a bookmark / section inside a webpage, we've to do this:

`<a id='section-2'>Section 2</a>`

so that we can link to it like this:

`<a href='page.php#section-2' >Click</a>`

**But why the site is recommending using anchor tag around "Section 2"? -When it can be done using span:**

`<span id='section-2'>Section 2</span>`

Are there compatibility issues? Because the first [search result](http://www.benchmarkemail.com/help-FAQ/answer/how-do-i-create-a-bookmark-within-my-webpage-and-link-to-it-from-my-email) for "creating bookmarks within a webpage" also says to surround the heading with anchor tag:

`<p><a name="title">Title</p>`

Though this particular example is incorrect for various other reasons.

I've a supplementary question:

Why to surround the heading with the container when it can be done simply like this:

`<span id='section-2'></span>Section 2`

Does it matter?

`<span id='section-2'>Sec</span>tion 2`

`<a href='page.php#section-2' >Click</a>`

Comment: what if that was a floating div ?

Comment: This is how it was done long ago, before `<span>` and `<div>` were added to HTML. Why do you think `<a>` is called "anchor"?

Comment: Also, your first source isn't super reputable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no point. W3schools is unreliable, just don’t use it, and you will avoid confusion and wrong information; see http://w3fools.com

In the old days, the only way to set a destination anchor within a page was to use `<a name=...>...</a>` element (at the text level). Later, the `id` attribute was added and is now supported by all browsers in use, so you can make any element a destination anchor simply by attaching an `id` attribute to it. E.g., to make it possible to link to a heading like `<h2>Section 2</h3>`, you could make it just `<h2 id=section-2>Section 2</h2>`. No need for an artificial extra element.

Using `<span id='section-2'></span>Section 2`, though formally correct, is not a good idea. You win nothing by using it, as opposite to the more logical markup. And if you e.g. later want to style (highlight) the element to which the user has “jumped” into with a link, using the `:target` pseudo-class, you will find yourself in an awkward position: the pseudo-class would let you style just the empty content of the `span`.

Regarding the question in the title, there is no reason to make the top of a page an destination anchror, with `<a id='top'>Top of page</a>` or otherwise. First, you can refer to the start of the page using just `href=#` since by URL specifications, `#` denotes the start of the current resource. Second, [“Back to top” links are basically useless or worse](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/totop.html): every browser has a simple command for going to the start of the page, and an explicit “Back to top” link can be confusing: back to top of *what*?

Answer (score 3):

In the early days of html an anchor element was the only way to do this, but just because you *can* now do it with other element types doesn't mean you *should:* using an anchor for this purpose is semantically correct because it makes it clear to anybody reading or maintaining your markup that the element is *intended* as a navigation target. (Noting that there will often be many elements on the page that have an id but are not navigation targets.)

> *"Why to surround the heading with the container when it can be done simply like this:* 
>   `<span id='section-2'></span>Section 2`

Because if you put the text of your heading inside an element you can style it and/or easily mess with it from JavaScript. Indeed, if it is a heading you may want to put it in an `<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc. tag rather than a `<span>`.